# Java client launched by Eclipse on Windows is unable to connect to remote Hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, cloudera

I'm unable to connect with my java client launched by Eclipse on Windows to my remote hdfs server.

My hdfs server runs on Cloudera Express 5.12.1 with Hadoop 2.6.0.
It works on mac os but I get the following error on windows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: End of File Exception between local host is: *HOST_IP*; destination host is: *DESTINATION_IP*:8020; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Here is my java client code :

```
package wordcount;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      InsertFile();
    }

    public static void InsertFile() throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://niko:8020");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FileStatus[] fsStatus = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"));
        for(int i = 0; i < fsStatus.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(fsStatus[i].getPath().toString());
        }
    } 
}
```

and the pom.xml file I'm using for Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.niko</groupId>
    <artifactId>WorldCount</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0-cdh5.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```